# Load a carousel content slider via Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Content slider: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/featuredcontentslider.htm
Ajax include script: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/ajaxcontent.htm

Content slider works correctly when both files and codes are (directly) in the HTML file.

But when I am retrieving the content slider to a HTML page via above ajax include script, while the JS file of the content slider is in the header of the HTML file, the content slider does not work. How can I get it working?

Thanks, pnm123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an answer...

Use jQuery instead above ajax include script.

```
<div id="a_unique_div_id"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#a_unique_div_id').load('content_slider.php');
</script>
```